# UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage not matching image from image picker view

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use the square image displayed on the preview screen of the UIImagePickerController but the image always come out pushed down slightly.

See the following pictures.

[image]
[image]

I have imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES, and here is the code once the image is selected.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imageEdited = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imgView.image = imageEdited;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The imgView has dimension of 320x320.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by hiding the navigation bar:

```
[navi setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```